# What is the most effective raiding strategy/loadout to earn resources?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been playing the game a while, and as you get to higher levels there is a significant need to stockpile large quantities of resources before you can start the higher level upgrades (Town Hall level 9, Clan Castle Level 4, Barracks Dragons upgrade, etc).  In order to accomplish this without racking up a huge credit card bill, it seems that you have to raid frequently and win big jackpots each time you do so.  I have found this to be very challenging because:

- I can usually only string together 2-3 attacks feasibly, due to the time it takes to train units.
- Related to the previous point, I often spend almost my entire stock of units during a raid, in order to win.
- Also related, I have the tough choice of training strong units which take ***forever*** to train and are very expensive, or weak ones which train quick and cheap but get wiped out rapidly.
- I often find it hard to even ***find*** opponents with big stockpiles, and when I do I often can't beat them.

I see other folks climbing the ranks and getting the big upgrades, so I know there must be a better way.  So what's the most effective unit loadout and/or strategy to get big resource payouts (sufficient to get the high level upgrades)?

Answer (score 6):

A strategy that works for me is the standard giant-healer attack. Find and take out the air defense close to you by distracting the defenses with a couple troops, use a few wall-breakers to break the wall. Then send as many giants as needed to take out the air defense. Then you can deploy the healer and the giants will destroy most of the defenses with nearly no trouble, provided no air defenses. However, problems can often arise with this strategy. The wall breakers could die, the giants could switch to a different target. In the event of this, I find a healing spell as a good way to keep the giants alive until it is safe to deploy the healer. Place it in the spot the giants will go, or in the center of them if there attacking. For clan castle troops, a few troops will do the job. Usually a lightning spell can quickly kill a mob of archers/barbarians. Even if the air defense is still there, deploy the healer as far from it as possible. YOU NEED THOSE GIANTS! Anyway, once the defenses somewhere are taken out, deploy archers or barbs to take out some stuff. If something is out of range of a defense, shoot it down. I have used this strategy for a month, and it is very effective. I have not lost one battle since I started doing this. Understand this works differently for everyone. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is pretty expensive and takes time to train. And moreover this strategy only works for town hall 6 and below.

Answer (score 4):

**Two words: Collector. Raiding.**

Raiding storages deep inside a base is costly, time consuming, and error prone.

What you want to find is a base that is idle, where the collectors have filled up and are near/outside the outer walls.  With practice you'll see the signs - no league shield, gold bins full, etc.  Finding one can take a while, so have enough gold on hand to skip 50-100 bases to find one.

Drop troops around the outside and destroy the collectors, then end the battle or fight on to 50% to conserve trophies.

Collector raiding can be done with a wide variety of troop loadouts, but one of the easiest and most popular is [BARCH](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/tips-tricks-rapid-raiding-around-town-hall-7-clash-clans/) (Barbs & Archers) or a variant like BAM (BARCH+Minions).

At TH7 and TH8, I can typically find bases with 150k to 300k resources within 50-100 skips.  The troop training cost is usually around 15-20k for this, depending on your troop ratios and troop levels.  The skip cost for 50 skips is 29k at TH8.

That yields a profit of somewhere between 100k and 250k of both gold and elixir per raid.  Couple that with the fast training time of the required troops, maybe throw in some boosted barracks, and you'll be maxing out your storages in no time flat.

With the addition of level 12 collectors, the profit margin has a chance to be even higher still.

Comment: This is the most sensible answer and deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

I find that using a barbarian-archer-goblin-barbarian king works the best. I have level 4 barbs level 3 archers and level 3 goblins but I find it really easy. I have 200 troop capacity and I use about 50 of each with the remaining 50 to use on 4 giants 5 wall breakers and 4 wizards. this works well and I usually get 100k-400k per raid gold and elixir combined.

Comment: Hi @ConnorVanDerWerff, welcome to Arqade!  I edited your answer to only include details related to the question.  Arqade is a little different than forum sites, in that format is strictly question and answer.  If you want to advertise for your clan, you could do so in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), but I think you'll find there aren't that many folks that play CoC here anyway.  As for your answer itself, I'm curious - do you deploy the whole group at once, or in a different arrangement?  You can edit your answer to add detail if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

This is funny because I just upgraded my town hall to level 9 and upgraded my barracks to dragons last night!   I boosted my Barracks and then I made Barbarians,   180 of them.   In that huge mass they can wipe out and destroy most of my opponents.   Also I did some goblin missions and racked up LOADS of resources without deactivating my shield.   So they may be weak separate   But as one. Barbarians ROCK!

Comment: Hi @LandenJohnson - Welcome to Arqade!  So you would recommend filling your camps with Barbarians and sending them en masse?  How do you deploy them (all in one spot, or distributed)?  Also, what level are they?

Comment: They are melee troops, attempting to break walls without wall breakers is nothing but suicide attack. Mortars/Wizard towers can wipe out barbarians while they are trying to break the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Using 250 gems to have a week shield is still the best way to earn guaranteed resources. You can set up a marathon raiding session. Once your resources are built up to a level that makes you nervous to lose, buy a shield for a week. This is the least expensive risk free way to build resources. When you get to day 6 and 23 hours, you can use those resources to upgrade your town hall or other expense structures that require gold or elixir.

This is assuming you've already maxed out your gold and elixir production (e.g. Level 11 as of my post).

Answer (score 1):

I have level 9 town hall and I'm usually in between 1500 and 2000 trophies. The giant and healer method works the best for me. I usually obtain all the villages resources which is sometimes as much as 400,000 each. Just remember take out those air defenses and make sure there are no clan castle troops and you're golden!

Comment: `Just remember take out those air defenses` Care to explain how do you intend to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

a strategy thats works well is 24 balloons, 40 minions, and 3 lightning spells.
check the clan castle to see if there is troops inside first, 
if there is troops inside use the lightning spell to destroy them
if not use the 3 lightning spells on an air defense,
send in the balloons first then minion, the balloons would work as a distraction and the minions would do most of the work.
i hope this helps

Comment: That is quite an expensive army composition. You need to look for bases with minimum 200k elixir to profit

Answer (score 1):

I myself have been playing for long and I have got massive upgrades done quite easily.
Attacking/raiding is as important as defending your resources.

Adapt the farming strategy i.e. place your town hall outside your walls so that the trophies-seeking players could simply attack your townhall and give away shield to you.

Q.How does this help now? 
A.Once you have started raiding and collecting resources, there are other players out there just like you who would want to raid and collect resources and they would attempt it on you and take a lot of it away in a splash. Now if you have your town hall outside, you would find that there are much larger number of players who give heed to number of trophies and they would come and destroy your town hall using a few archers/barbs and give you a shield for 12 hours. In the mean time you go out, be busy, do your office. And at the end of the day find your previously collected resources intact.

Secondly, attacking is equally important.
A tip that worked for me is - Drop your trophies to around 1200, change your language to japanese, (yes, changing language shows you only those players who are currently playing using the same language settings), search for players with huge loot amount, try to strategize if you would be able to get the loot or not using the troops you use.
Be it giants, healer strat, hogs-balloon strat, or anything.
What matters is that you have to find something with a base that is not too strong for you to raid. And there is plenty of loot out there, you would come across super easy loots.
Although changing the language is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 dragons and 8 giants which uses 80 space then i still have 110 space left so i will get 40 archers 5-10 wall breakers and the rest barbarians and wizards some times ill take out 5 giants and put in a pekka

Comment: Could you [edit] to improve your answer by explaining *why* this is a good strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the strategy I use,

3 Dragons

11 Hog-Riders

15 Archers

15 Barbarians

15 Goblins

Barb king and Archer Queen

I have capacity 200 And I usually win! just a suggestion!

Usually my trophies are between gold one and crystal three!

hope this helps!

Comment: ` And I usually win!` Well the original question was how to raid effectively. This clearly is not effective raiding (assuming that you use all the above mentioned troops)

Answer (score -1):

100 archers, 75 barbarians, 25 Goblins, level 5 barb king. My storages always full.

Comment: Could you edit to improve your answer by explaining why this is a good strategy?

Answer (score -1):

I use all goblins. Its a great strategy actually. Im in silver three but I have 200 space and in silver three I get about 400k gold and elixer each raid! Just from collectors!

Comment: You need to be more specific, go deeper with your explanation and consider the effort of the person asking.